# How to test interactivity of React component using D3 select()?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, reactjs

I have a React visualization component (Using SVG) that displays a tooltip on mouseOver, using the `d3.select()` function to modify a class on the tooltip element so that it becomes visible (And invisible on mouseOut):

```
_handleMouseOverEvent: function() {
    d3.select('#' + this.props.caption).classed('hidden', false);
    d3.select('#' + this.props.caption).classed('visible', true);
} 
_handleMouseOutEvent: function() {
    d3.select('#' + this.props.caption).classed('visible', false);
    d3.select('#' + this.props.caption).classed('hidden', true);
}
```

I'm having some difficulty writing a test for this using the React TestUtils:

```
chart = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
    <SvgVisualization data={testData}/>
);

var chartElement = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass('className');    

TestUtils.Simulate.mouseOver(chartElement); // I also tried with chart.getDOMNode() and SimulateNative

var tooltip = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithId('tooltipId');
expect(tooltip.getDOMNode().classList).to.contain('visible');
```

From debugging it appears that the `d3.select()` call returns nothing. This works fine in my application.

The tests are being run in PhantomJS via the karma test runner. (The expect() is from Chai). Is there anything I could do differently to make this testable? Do PhantomJS and D3 simply not co-operate in this way?

I'm going to add a WebDriver-type test for this bit of functionality but generally prefer to add the karma tests as these are run in our pre-push hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this issue by rewriting the code: Now, instead of rendering everything with `display: none` and modifying this through the event callbacks, we modify the component `state` in `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` and use that state to decide whether or not to render in the `render` method. It works great, and uses React much more "properly" than the previous implementation.